# Windows file server permissions mistake - Everyone denied !

Tags: windows, permissions, share

I just made a big mistake. I set the Everyone group Deny permissions on a folder shared..
How do I recover that ?

Please help..

Comment: Share permissions, or on the directory? Sounds like the directory on the local filesystem...

Comment: Yes it's on the directory itself..

Comment: I have the samilar problem, I just set a file permission everyone denied. and I can't edit its permission or delete it even as an administrator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take ownership of the folder. Remove the deny entry.

Comment: Yes indeed. It is the only way.

Comment: I'm already folder's owner (Administrator), but how to remove the deny entry ? 

When trying to access the Security tab, I have a message : "You do not have permission to view the current permission settings for XXXXXX, but you can make permission changes.", then the list of users/group with associated permissions is empty !

Comment: Then I try to Add the Everyone user, I modify the permissions to Full control Allow but it refuses with : "Unable to save permission changes on XXXXX. Access is denied".

Comment: Ok, there is something strange. When I first check the owner it was set to Administrator as I said. But I closed the window and reopened it, and now it was "Don't have the permission to display the owner" or something like that. I was able to get back the ownership and correct the permissions. 

Thank you

Comment: @ack__ Ensure you are re-taking the ownership correctly.  On the Ownership tab, reselect Administrator in the Change to section. Click Apply.  This should allow you to delete the Everyone entry on the Security tab.